# Running GRPC example for golang

Tags: go, grpc

newbie here.

Currently learning how grpc works and was going through the tutorial in this link 
https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/go.html#update-and-run-the-application

When I ran the example using the `helloworld.pb.go` file provided, it works. But when I deleted that file and ran  `protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto` to generate the that file again, I find that I can no longer run the greeter server.

The error I am getting is

> google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld
>   helloworld/helloworld.pb.go:105:11: cannot use _Greeter_SayHello_Handler (type func(interface {}, "context".Context, grpc.Codec, []byte) (interface {}, error)) as type grpc.methodHandler in field value

Tried to google but couldn't find out why. My protobuf version is 3.5.1 and the grpc is freshly cloned from `github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go`

Comment: Do you have a different version of go grpc library vendored?

Comment: Maybe try updating both proto plugins: go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}?

Comment: I updated both and it still doesnt work...

Comment: I would download the example again and have a look at the method signature for `_Greeter_SayHello_Handler`
.Generate the file again using the protoc command. If the signature is different then your protoc-gen-go is mismatched. Delete any binary protoc in your $PATH and install again.

Answer (score 0):

Generate proto like this

file_name : Your proto file name with the path

```
//To generate the grpc code 
protoc proto/file_name.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:.
```

Take a look this link How to write proto and generate the proto file. It may help your problem

https://github.com/SXerox007/protos-